# How would I design this table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have a parent master table that is generic enough to hold the common information of the children. Since the children were substantially different, we created separate tables for them. So I have something like this:

```
tblMaster
--------
MasterID int
Name varchar(50) --Common to all children and there are a bunch of fields like this
ChildType int -- Type of Child either ChildOne or ChildTwo
ChildID int -- need to store ChildOneID or ChildTwoID depending on type of Child, so that i can refer to children

tblChild1
--------
ChildOneID int IDENTITY

tblChild2
---------
ChildTwoID int IDENTITY
```

Should I have a `ChildID` in the master that is either `ChildOneID` or `ChildTwoID` based on the `ChildType` column? I have a number of children and I have simplified it for this question.

The other way is to add `ChildOneID` and `ChildTwoID` as columns in the master, but since i have a number of columns, I will have a lot of null columns

**EDIT: Any help is appreciated**

Comment: @Taz - In reality, I have 10 of them and that's why I wanted to stay way from adding 10 columns in the master

Comment: do children have any colums themselves? and are those different for all 10 children?

Comment: @Taz - No, children dont have children.

Comment: Why is a parent table holding information about a child?

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call it a parent child as it's a one to one relationship.

Comment: More like a master-detail type. One question: does 'Common to all children' mean that a master item can have several children (or detail items)? It's just caught my eye, though otherwise the structure here does not seem to allow such a scheme. (If only you were not going to duplicate the master item to reference all the children.) Anyway, detail rows referencing the master row seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the identity in the id of the master, then use that same id in the appropriate child table as I show below.

### tblMaster

ID int Identity
Name varchar(50) --Common to all children and there are a bunch of fields like this
ChildType int    -- Type of Child either ChildOne or ChildTwo

### tblChild1

ID int

### tblChild2

ID int

Comment: Since it's a IDENTITY column, the tblMaster.ID will have duplicate values. I guess this is okay as we have a ChildType but somehow doesn't sound right

Comment: I don't understand your comment RSharma.  The master table's id is an identity and the primary key. The child tables id's are gotten from the corresponding master's id, but they are not identities, but are primary keys.  No duplicates in master, no duplicates in child. Child will have holes in id, but who cares?

Comment: Do you mean that tblChild*.ID would be both a foreign key and the primary key?

Comment: @Andriy Yes, Primary key of the child table and a foreign key into the parent table.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just have.

```
tblMaster
--------
MasterID int
Name varchar(50) --Common to all children and there are a bunch of fields like this

tblChild1
--------
ChildOneID int IDENTITY
MasterID int

tblChild2
---------
ChildTwoID int IDENTITY
MasterID int
```

?

Assuming each child has one parent, otherwise setup a join table. if its many to many.

Answer (score 0):

Adding columns per child is bad design, as you need to keep changing the table design as and when a new child types comes. Use foreign key reference of the master table id in the child table

Comment: Maybe the use of "parent-child" is incorrect as all these tables are one to one

Comment: They are not strictly [1 to 1] but [1 to 0 or 1].